# How to rotate the central axis of object to the given direction?

Tags: python, algorithm, rotation

The object and central axis vector of that object is given.

The central axis vector of the object starts from the origin (0,0,0) like on the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Sja.jpg

How can i rotate the whole object so the other end of the central axis (orange point on the picture) land on the z axis like on the picture?

Comment: If you can define the problem as "rotation axis can be calculated from cross-product between the central axis vector and z-direction vector", what you have to do becomes to 2D rotation.

Comment: This question isn’t about programming, just math (which has its own StackExchange site).